# Django migrations: how to generate database from current state of the models (good old syncdb --all)

Tags: django

Usually, when I started working on a django+south project that had been in development for some time I didn't bother with applying all hundreds of migrations just to get to the current state of the database. I went straight for `syncdb --all` to create a database from the current model state then run `migrate --fake` to mark all migrations as passed.

In a matter of **few seconds** I had a database which was in sync with migrations. `Syncdb` loaded initial fixtures. 99% cases this was all I needed. I was very happy.

How can I do that now? `Syncdb` is deprecated and the `migrate` command doesn't have an option to ignore migrations and just create the database from the current state of the model classes.

Migrate command makes me go through tons of migrations from many months of project development. These migrations have some weird errors I don't even care about. It is also extremely slow as if something was messed up in the implementation of the migration engine.

I just want to be able to say: "hey, Django, this is the model, create me a database from the model, then fake all migrations and let's work from there".

I know I can delete all migrations locally, create initials for all apps and apply them but this seems like a very weird workaround for an equivalent of `syncdb --all`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I guess you could just re-create your migrations from the models you have and run the result.

Comment: pytest does exactly this for running tests, so this functionality obviously exists. It's just not easily accessible.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `--fake` flag for doing that. it will ignore all passed migrations and start migrating from now on. like this:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

also if you want to set current state of your migrations (for example assume that your last migration on an app is on 0004_... which starts with `0004`)

```
python manage.py migrate --fake my_app 0004
```

**Note**

also there are some options too:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake my_app zero

python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```